# NO 3D after installing updates on fresh Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ati, 3d, 2d

I've just purchased my laptop HP Pavilion G7-1390ED. My Graphic card is AMD Radeon HD7450M with 1gb ram.

First after i installed ubuntu 12.04 3D was working fine, but after installing other updates including AMD Radeon video drivers and restart 3D is not working. It only runs with 2d.

I hope someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Does this laptop come with an integrated board as well? If so, you should take a look at the [bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) project.

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I had the same issue with another Radeon graphic card and I deactivated the proprietary drivers: 3D came again.

Answer (score 0):

The FGLRX drivers use modules, these modules are installed with pre confugration to use in the *current* kernel you were using at the moment of installation, now if a recall there was an update to the kernel, so you need to re-run the installer again for the modules to be built for the new kernel.

This same happens in Virtualbox for example, so that's why you don't have compositing available.