# Why did Unity stop working after I upgraded to the 3.4.3 mainline kernel?

Tags: unity, upgrade, kernel

I [installed the latest Linux kernel](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/06/how-to-install-linux-kernel-343-on.html) (3.4.3). After rebooting, it says I am in Ubuntu 2D. How do I either go back to my previous kernel, or fix this problem? Thanks.

```
$ uname -r
3.4.3-030403-generic
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NO 3D after installing updates on fresh Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153291/no-3d-after-installing-updates-on-fresh-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kernel apparently lacks drivers needed for Unity support, as it's a mainline kernel without Ubuntu added code and drivers.

To go back to your old kernel:

- Reboot and right after your system finishes the self-test (POST) routine, press the **left shift** key and keep it pressed until you get to the GRUB menu.
- Select "Previous Linux versions" and boot with a 3.2-series kernel
- If you want to remove the non-working kernel, open a terminal and type

  `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-generic=3.4.3`